# iOS Simulator Error: NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code 3 - No such process

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, posix

**Details:**  Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code: 3 Failure Reason: No such process User Info: {     DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-31 06:29:07 +0000";     IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;     SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:"; }

Application launch for 'org.reactjs.native.example.example' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process

**System Information**

macOS Version 13.4.1 (c) (Build 22F770820d)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)

**Issue with Mach-0 Type:**
I am trying to install the ios app on simulator, I changed mach-O type to bundle, after inferring an error on executable type, Following errors occurred with executable type

Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

Linker command failed with exit code 1

**UPDATE**

I resolved this error, just by hardcoding my bundle identifier

Bundle Identifier: org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME)

I replaced bundle identifier value with com.xyz

where PRODUCT_NAME = xyz

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue when I wanted to run my project on a new mac.
It doesn't have anything to do with the code, since on other macs (Intel, Apple M1, including CI) it runs fine.

So the issue was on my mac, for some reason by installing rosseta worked:

```
$ softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Source [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727818?answerId=751501022#751501022)

Comment: I had rosetta already installed but was still getting this error. Good installing rosetta solved this bug